# How to stop the mouse pointer from changing to an I beam when hovering over a readonly textbox in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, mouse-cursor

Is there any way to stop the mouse pointer from changing to an I beam when hovering over a readonly textbox in Windows 10 UWP? I don't see any properties in the `TextBox` control that would do this. Ideally, it would be good if I can do this in XAML without going to code behind. Please help!

Comment: Isnt the text in the box still selectable though?

Comment: @BugFinder No, i have set `AllowFocusOnInteraction` to `false`

Comment: If you don't want the text to be selected or edited, why don't you use `TextBlock` then?

Comment: @MDMuziburRahman I need this behaviour only when `IsReadOnly` is `true`

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You can add another layer of transparent visual over it, like a transparent fill `Rectangle` when the value of  `IsReadOnly` Property is true, and remove it when it is false.